# Read register from text file

Tags: c, file

Im trying to read the first register from a text with a name and an ID separated by '|':

```
Jhon|33232323
Ricky|32222222
Michael|36333111
```

I used fprintf previously to print with format from a binary to a text file, so i supposed i could use fscanf to scan from a file with format.

```
FILE *pf=fopen("D:\\Juan\\binarioATexto\\variable.txt","rt");
if(!pf)exit(1);

student stud;

fscanf(pf,"%s|%ld",stud.nombre,&stud.dni);

printf("%s %ld",stud.nombre,stud.dni);

fclose(pf);

return 0;
```

The result is: Jhon|33232323 0

Why i can not use fscanf()?

Comment: Please post `student` structure

Comment: `%s` won't stop at the `|`... it'll read until the end of the line since there's no whitespace before that.  Try `%[^|]` (though you should add a max width).  Also, check the result of `fscanf()` to make sure all the fields were scanned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the manual page for [fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf). With this information in mind the format string should be

```
fscanf(pf, "%[^|]|%ld\n", stud.nombre,&stud.dni);
```